# I'm not sure I'm applying the Rails change migration properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, decimal, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building a Rails application that allows a user to catalogue tires by inputting values into the UI. When I created the `tire` class , I made it as

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :tires do |t|
      t.decimal :price
      ...
  end
end
```

When I ran the program I realized that I'd neglected to specify the precision and scale of the `decimal` attribute. This resulted in the program being unable to accept non-integer values and displaying all values appended by `.0` Because I was so much farther along on the program, I decided to write another migration to just change `price` to a `float` by writing the following migration:

```
class ChangeTiresToFloat < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    change_column :tires, :price, :float
   end
```

After running `db:migrate`, there is no change in the behavior of the program. Should this not have made it so that the UI could accept float values?

Edit: Before resorting to making the `price` column a float value, I did try to fix the `decimal` value by adding the missing attributes with this migration:

```
class MoneyDecimalFix < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    change_column :tires, :price, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
  end
end
```

After rolling forward the migration, the program's behavior still did not change.

Comment: Don't use floats for prices. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: Agree with @max you can use a money library like https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails

Comment: Although I am planning to switch to the Money library on an optimization update after this, I'd first like to know what my error is in implementing the migration. Why it is that rolling it forward results in no change to the program's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to use a `change_column` migration to edit the price value to include the `decimal` attribute's specifications, because the `create_table` is a reversible migration, it is advisable to instead roll the migration back and manually implement the change to ultimately read

`t.decimal :price, :precision => 8, :scale => 2`

then roll the migration forward again.

It is however worth noting that, although having the `price` column correctly defined in the migration is an essential step, it alone did not fix the issue of the form not accepting decimal values.

The error was ultimately in my Views. Within Rails, the `number_field` tag, on its own, will not accept decimal values, it must be 'combined' with a `text_field` tag in order to do so as such:

`<%= f.number_field :price, class: :text_field, step: :any %>`